# Function closures and meaning of <locals> syntax in object name in Python

Tags: python, syntax

Suppose I have the following code:

```
def outer(information):
    print(locals())
    def inner():
        print("The information given to me is: ", information)
    return inner


func1 = outer("info1")
print(func1)
```

It returns:

```
{'information': 'info1'}
<function outer.<locals>.inner at 0x1004d9d30>
```

Of course, if I call `func1`, it will print with info1 in the statement. So, from printing the locals() in the outer function, I can see that there is some relationship between the local scope and the storage of the argument.

I was expecting func1 to simply be `outer.inner`, why does the syntax instead say `outer.<locals>.inner`? Is this a syntactical way of clarifying that there are different local scopes associated to each of these functions - imagine I made another one `func2 = outer("info2")` - I return using the outer function?

Also, is there something special about the enclosing <> syntax when used around a name? I see it around both the object and locals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [PEP 3155 -- Qualified name for classes and functions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/) and the [example with nested functions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/#example-with-nested-functions).

> For nested classes, methods, and nested functions, the `__qualname__` attribute contains a dotted path leading to the object from the module top-level. A function's local namespace is represented in that dotted path by a component named `<locals>`.

Since the `__repr__` of a function uses the `__qualname__` attribute, you see this extra component in the output when printing a nested function.

> I was expecting func1 to simply be `outer.inner`

That's not a fully qualified name. With this repr you might mistakenly assume you could import the name `outer` and dynamically access the attribute `inner`. Remember the qualname is a "dotted path leading to the object", but in this case attribute access is not possible because `inner` is a local variable.

> Also, is there something special about the enclosing <> syntax when used around a name?

There is nothing special about it, but it gives a pretty strong hint to the programmer that you can't access this namespace directly, because the name is not [a valid identifier](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

Answer (score 1):

You can think of `outer.<locals>.inner` as saying that inner is a local variable created by the function. `inner` is what is referred to a closure in computer science. Roughly speaking a closure is like a lambda in that it acts as a function, but it requires non-global data be bundled with it to operate. In memory it acts as a tuple between information and a reference to the function being called.

```py
foo = outer("foo")
bar = outer("bar")

# In memory these more or less looks like the following:
("foo", outer.inner)
("bar", outer.inner)

# And since it was created from a local namespace and can not be accessed
# from a static context local variables bundled with the function, it
# represents that by adding <local> when printed.

# While something like this looks a whole lot more convenient, it gets way
# more annoying to work with when the local variables used are the length of
# your entire terminal screen.
<function outer."foo".inner at 0x1004d9d30>
```

There is nothing inherently special about the <> other than informing you that `<local>` has some special meaning.

#### Edit:

I was not completely sure when writing my answer, but after seeing @wim's answer `<local>` not only applies to closures created consuming variables within a local context. It can be applied more broadly to all functions (or anything else) created within a local namespace. So in summary `foo.<local>.bar` just means that "bar was created within the local namespace of foo".

Comment: Ok, I think I see, so <local> is just a placeholder that's telling us, "hey there are these things defined in the local scope you should be aware of, but we're not going to show everything"

Comment: Yea, plus the function is in itself a local variable as well.